# How to delete all records from realm object without fetching it in android?

Tags: android, realm

I have 1 realm object and some records inside it. I want to make the object having empty records without fetching it, in a single transaction.

```
RealmResults<Movie> movies = realm.where(Movie.class).findAll();
movies.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Now we have like this but I want something like the following without the first line.

```
realm.deleteAll(Movies.class);
```

Is there anything like this? I don't know, may be it will take less time to delete. I am just worried about the time it is taking to delete. In my application I have 10 objects having more than 200,000 records.

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#delete-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.delete(Movies.class);
    }
});
```

In older Realm versions, it was called `Realm.clear(Movies.class);`.